# What do I need to do and know to find an extremum of a function in a parallelogram?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, computational-mathematics

I think in a very short time on my work, I will be face issue of a finding extremum points of a restricted functions. What math topic it is? I didn't find any similar problems in multivariable calculus.

Comment: Maybe, Largrange multipliers have to do with what you search.

Comment: You need to use the first derivative test to find minimum and maximum values of a function, and then use Lagrange multipliers to test out the boundaries of the domain.